# How to change :term into edit split in vim

Tags: vim

I have a split open with ":term" (!/bin/zsh [running]) how can I change it to an edit split?
I cannot write ":edit file" as the ":term" split doesn't allow me to get into the normal/command mode.

Comment: Vim's documentation should have been your first stop: `:help terminal-typing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between the terminal and your code by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>. And while you inside the vim window, you can use Command mode. Did I understood your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a terminal by an edit window of a "foo" file do

`Crtl-W :e! foo`

You need "!" to close the shell of the terminal.

BTW if you have a edit window, you can split it with Crtl-W S, you don't need to use :term.